# How to update current running production level Hyperledger 1.4v to v2.0.1

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I was using the previous version of hyperledger fabric 1.4.x in my production level, Now I need to update to hyperledger 1.4.x to 2.0.1 latest version. Is it possible to upgrade the production level data to support the new version of hyperledger? what all the steps I need to follow please help me on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [fabric's official documentation](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/), in particular the chapter [Upgrading to the latest release](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.1/upgrade.html).
Always make sure to look at the proper version of the documentation - see bottom left corner where you can select the version.